# OpenAI transcription API returns 400 bad request

Tags: javascript, openai-api, transcription, openai-whisper

Any idea why the API returns a 400 error? I verified that the MP3 file exists and the authorization is being added to the header of the request.

```js
async function transcribeAudio() {
  const configuration = new Configuration({
    apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY,
  });

  const openai = new OpenAIApi(configuration)

  const response = await openai.createTranscription(
    fs.createReadStream('./audio.mp3'), // The audio file to transcribe.
    "whisper-1", // The model to use for transcription.
    undefined, // The prompt to use for transcription.
    'json', // The format of the transcription.
    1, // Temperature
    'en' // Language
  )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Initially, I was facing the same `400 status` code issue. There is some problem with `openai npm package`.
The below code works for me.

Here, I am using their `api` to get the `transcription`.

```
import FormData from "form-data";
import axios from 'axios'

const transcribe = async (file) => {
  let data = new FormData();

  data.append("file", fs.createReadStream(file));
  data.append("model", "whisper-1");
  data.append("language", "en");

  let config = {
    method: "post",
    maxBodyLength: Infinity,
    url: "https://api.openai.com/v1/audio/transcriptions",
    headers: {
      Authorization:
        `Bearer ${process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY}`,
      "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
      ...data.getHeaders(),
    },
    data: data,
  };

  try {
    const response = await axios.request(config);
    const data = response.data;

    return { data };
  } catch (error) {
    return {};
  }
};
```

Here's how you can use the above function.

```
(async () => {
  const transcription = await transcribe('./audio.mp3');
  console.log("transcription: ", transcription)
})()
```

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out, I was extracting audio from youtube and feeding it to the API, but the API doesn't support the youtube audio format

Comment: So, how did you solve this problem?

Comment: There are libraries that can convert m4a to mp4, since I was just playing around I didn't bother with the conversion, I just fed it a proper supported audi file

Comment: Thanks for the question, response and discussion. This is great stuff!